# c++ Is it possible to create a constructor in a derived class that is not based on its base class?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, constructor-overloading

Executing the code below will give an error to the line `Child(){/**........code*/}` saying: no matching function for call to 'Base::Base()' and that canditate Base::Base(int) expects 1 argument, and none is provided.

```
class Base
{

public:
    Base(int test)
    {

    };

};

class Child : public Base
{

public:
    Child ()
    {
        /**....
           ....
           code*/
    };
    Child(int test):Base(test)
    {

    };
};
```

So I would like to know if there is a way to use a constructor in the derived class - for example: `Child(){};` - that doesn't  have any association with its base class.

Comment: I would guess the simplest way is either to just give your child class the BASE cunstructor and hand over some dummy value, or you would need to create a `base:base(){}` constructor

Answer (score 5):

No.

By your definition a `Child` inherits from `Base` and it is not possible to create a `Child` without the `Base` subobject.

Instead you should provide an argument (whatever is a good default):

```
Child() : Base(42) {};
```

Alternatively `Base` could provide a default constructor (one that can be called without arguments), that would be

```
class Base {
public:
    Base(int test = 42) {};    
};
```

then your `Child` would be ok as is.

Answer (score 0):

You still need to call the user defined constructor. You can however pass a dummy argument to it if your application will tolerate that. Otherwise, it is bad application design and something will break somewhere later on.

```
class Child : public Base
{

public:
    Child ()
         : Base(0)
    {
        /**....
           ....
           code*/
    };
    Child(int test):Base(test)
    {

    };
};
```